# BASH/GNU Tar - pipe output to function

Tags: bash, pipe, output, tar

Im trying to extract a common tar.gz file. I currently have:

```
function streamLog()
{
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        IN="$1"
    else
        read IN # This reads a string from stdin and stores it in a variable called IN
    fi

    if [ -z "${IN}" ]
    then
        return 0
    else
        echo "${IN}" >> zlib.log
    fi
}

/bin/tar --no-same-owner -zxvf ~/src/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz -C /build | streamLog
```

This causes a lot of files contained within zlib to fail to extract.  Wierdly some do tho.  I see no output send to my streamLog function which are unexpected.  This so far is the only command Ive had fail using this method.

I expect tar might be a special case.  Why would this happen?

What should I do to correctly get the output of a command streamed to a function?

Comment: does this happen when you run tar without `--no-same-owner` option ?

Comment: I guess `tar` maybe logs to `stderr` rather than `stdout`. Try `... 2>&1 | streamLog`